# I'm having trouble with this compilation error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner, and every time I open or create a project on any template, a message saying that my project contains compilation error appear and asks me to enter safe mode, it all started when I froze my computer with 2 unity projects, and had to forcefully shut my computer down. Then my computer wouldn't turn on, until my father helped me turn it on. Since then, Unity keeps showing me this message every time I open/create a project.

"The project you are opening contains compilation errors.

Entering safe mode allows you to resolve these errors without waiting for the rest of your project to import.

If you select ignore (not recomended), your project will continue to import, but may be in a broken or unusable state."

I'm worried that if this problem gets solved on one project it will still happen to later projects I create.

I tried reinstalling Unity and messing with the files, it didn't work.
I'm getting as much help as I can on this problem, and it didn't really solve anything.

Comment: You can try and create a new project - does that still show errors? What specific errors do you get? Does recompiling solve them or at least show details?

Comment: OT maybe also a good moment (or rather: a bit too late to help now) to look into source control (Git)

Comment: Your computer not turning on sounds a bit beyond what Unity could cause tbh ..

Answer (score 0):

Just open the project and click "Ignore" on that popup, and share the screenshot of all the compilation errors you see there.

It might be useful for others who find this thread to know all the other possible cases of this error:

1. The issue might be because of the issue while resolving the packages. Try to delete `./YourProjectName/Library/` directory and open Unity again.
2. Also, you might develop the project for let's say Android project using platform-dependent packages, but after restart, the platform returned to "Standalone Windows", so you just have to open the Player Settings and switch platform to Android back.
3. You just edited some C# scripts which currently are not compiling, so you have to correct your C# scripts.

Comment: If possible, please share the compilation errors as *text*

Comment: @Ivan Taranov I can link my post on reddit with the problems I had here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/103jiek/what_is_this_im_only_starting_now_so_i_dont_know/

Comment: @JúlioAlencarvieira, from what I see on your screenshots, you have to do the step in point 1 of my post: close Unity, delete Library directory and open the project again

Comment: Should I delete the files in safe mode, normal mode, or before I open the project?

Comment: @JúlioAlencarvieira remove Library when the Unity is closed